# HTTP request via RabbitMQ?

Tags: http, rabbitmq, google-cloud-functions

I am designing a system, one component of the system gives me approx 50 outputs. I then start up VM instances for each of the 50 outputs, pass the outputs as inputs and run a process which can take 10 - 60 minutes on each of the instances.

Currently, when I get my output data, what I do is add each output to a message queue (rabbitmq) and then send an HTTP request to a cloud function. This cloud function basically creates 'self-destructing' instances for each output. The HTTP request has the "number_of_req_instances" and then each instance acts as a consumer, and picks one task from the queue.

I was wondering, is there any way to send the HTTP request from rabbitmq? Or whats the best practice for handling this sort of use-case? I'm not entirely happy that my 'http-request' to create instances and the population of my queue are two steps.

I not only need to pass the output as input, but I also need to start up the instances. I also like the fact that RabbitMQ works quite well with the acknowledgement of messages, so I'm keen to keep that as part of the system. I could however use HTTP requests to pass all the information and feed it to the metadata of the instances. But that's not ideal since the HTTP response would be direct and I wouldn't know if any of the tasks failed as opposed to using RabbitMQ.

Any suggesstions?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into a solution with Cloud Function being triggered by a Pub/Sub message. The output would be sent to a topic in Pub/Sub. This topic is set as a trigger to launch the Function once a topic is published. The Cloud Function will ingest the Pub/Sub message containing the output and process the output.

You may look more into this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) for Cloud Function triggered by Pub/Sub. There is also some architecture references you might find interesting. ie The [serveless event driven](https://gcp.solutions/diagram/serverless-event-driven)